# java script to json

Tags: javascript, json

If I have an array like

```
price=["1@1000", "1000@2000"]
```

how to convert it into JSON so that it can be send into ajax call of jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '',
    data: {
        'price': price
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(data);
        var products = data.products;
        console.log(products);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already posted...parts of jQuery, here is a jQuery plugin that should do it

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/stringify

|EDIT| The jQuery-plugins-site is put down for a while.

Anyways, you a looking for a function called *Stringify*. You can read more about it here:

http://www.json.org/js.html

A simple google-search should give you plenty results.

Answer (score 0):

When writing `price=["1@1000", "1000@2000"]` you already have your data represented as a javascript array.
It should be possible for you to simply pass this as an argument as you have described within your use of the $.ajax method.
Alternatively (if you really need to parse price as a json object) see the jQuery builtin function for this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

But recheck that this is not just possible, as you have described it, if not, what errors are you getting?

Comment: That is wrong way. parseJSON takes a json-object and make a array out of it. He want to go the other way, and a built-in function like that does not exist in the jQuery framework as of today

Comment: Although I still have difficulties acknowledging that this is indeed needed, it might help to take a look at https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js that includes both encoder and decoder functions for json in JS.

Comment: I think most modern browser have a built in JSON parser/stringifier.